# how to reffer non static variable from static method?

Tags: java

Q)i got one compile error 10::non-static variable this can not be refferenced from the static content

what to do now??

```
class Computer
{    
  void method()    
  {    
     System.out.println("this i objects");
  }


   public static void main(String[] args)    
    {    
      Laptop mtd = new Laptop();
      Computer mtd1 = new Computer();
      mtd.method();
      mtd1.method();
     }  


class Laptop
  {    
    void method()    
     {    
      System.out.println("using laptop method");         
     }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: Your code is quite spacious.

Comment: i didnt gave that much space in original program @P45Imminent

Comment: So you added some for our pleasure? How can I express my gratitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop is an inner class of Computer, thus you have to instantiate Laptop from a Computer instance.  Or you can mark your inner Laptop class as static, then you can instantiate it directly.  My example demonstrates both approaches:

```
class Computer
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Computer computer = new Computer();
      computer.method();

      // Instantiate normal inner class from instance object.
      Laptop laptop = computer.new Laptop(); // Or: new Computer().new Laptop();
      laptop.method();

      // Instantiate static inner class directly.
      StaticLaptop staticLaptop = new StaticLaptop();
      staticLaptop.method();
  }

  void method()    
  {
      System.out.println("I'm Computer!");
  }


  class Laptop
  {
      void method()
      {
        System.out.println("I'm Laptop!");  
      }
  }

  static class StaticLaptop
  {
      void method()
      {
        System.out.println("I'm StaticLaptop!");  
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you very munch for your information @stephen henningsen

Answer (score 0):

You've put `Laptop` inside the `Computer` class.

You should refactor to `static class Laptop`. Otherwise you are tying a Laptop instance to a specific Computer instance, which you probably don't want to do. (If you *really* wanted to do that, you'd have to write `new Computer().new Laptop();`)

Although I think, in reality, you want to write

`class Laptop extends Computer`

which is called *inheritance*.

Comment: i am new to java language can u explian me what is refactor?? @p45Imminent

Comment: Just "change it to". That is, wack in the word `static` before your `class Laptop`